# Graph: Filter events by singleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to filter using single-value extended properties, according to the documentation:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get

I have a calendar with a large number of events (around 40k events). Each event has a property called 'ExpedienteId', and I am trying to filter by this property as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/myuser@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/calendars/CALENDARID/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {e363423c-3db9-4cf1-b2bf-3777d331d5e7} Name ExpedienteId' and ep/value eq '6313')
```

The first time I execute the request, I get this result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a848a095-983a-460e-a9bf-4089b22aa485",
            "date": "2017-10-18T12:47:07"
        }
    }
}
```

with a **503 Service Unavailable**.

However, the second time I execute the request, I received the right results (filtered) almost immediately (It looks like the query has been cached).

What is wrong with the first call? Is there any limitation for this type of filter?